# Proper JSON output in ZF2 without template rendering

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Is there any way to make proper JSON output work? (alternative to **$this->_heleper->json->SendJSON() in ZF1**)

```
    public function ajaxSectionAction() {
return new JsonModel(array(
    'some_parameter' => 'some value',
    'success' => true,
));
}
```

Bacause it throws an error:

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException'

> with message 'SmartyModule\View\Renderer\SmartyRenderer::render:

> Unable to render template ...
```

Answer (score 11):

Rob Allen has written an article about it:
[Returning JSON from a ZF2 controller action](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/returning-json-from-a-zf2-controller-action/)

If you want to return a JsonModel, You have to add JsonStrategy to your view_manager:

```
//module.config.php
return array(
    'view_manager' => array(
        'strategies' => array(
           'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),
    ),
)
```

Then return a JsonModel from action controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $result = new JsonModel(array(
        ...
    ));

    return $result;
}
```

Another way, Also you can try this code to return every data without view rendering:

```
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->setStatusCode(200);
$response->setContent('some data');
return $response;
```

You can try `$response->setContent(json_encode(array(...)));` or :

```
$jsonModel = new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel(array(...));
$response->setContent($jsonModel->serialize());
```

Comment: It's messy way, and I can't see advantages between this and Zend_Json::encode()

Comment: I updated answer. Best way is JsonModel and view strategies. But you can use Response to return every data such as json.